# How to pick a random place from a 2D array?

Tags: c#, random, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a console quiz game, and for this I need to pick random questions from random categories from a 2D array. But I'm not sure how to go about picking random from 2D arrays.

I cannot show my full arrays as they are very large - below is a trimmed version:

```
string[,] mineKategorier = new string[10, 6]
{
    {"C#","Question one here", "Question two here", "Question three here"},
    {"Spil engines", "Question one here", "Question two here", "Question three here"},
    {"Sport", "Question one here", "Question two here", "Question three here"},
};
```

Comment: The questions category is the first array element? This is messy. Read about enums and dictionaries. Also, a tip: Press alt while selecting text in Visual Studio and it will select a rectangular area rather than full lines. Do this with 4 spaces before the least-indented line and then pasting it to Stack Overflow should be solid. This just saves hard work to prettify the snippet.

Comment: Hmmm... makes me wonder if Microsoft invented multidimensional arrays `int[,]` and jagged arrays `int[][]` just to make mortal programmers understand they should stay very clear of arrays or if they just did it to be evil! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int row = rnd.Next(mineKategorier.GetLength(0));
int column = rnd.Next(mineKategorier.GetLength(1));

string randomKategori = mineKategorier[row, column];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to have only one `Random` object in your application. You can instantiate a `Random` object by doing:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

You can use this object to generate random questions as follows:

```
int categoryNumber = random.Next(mineKategorier.GetLength(0));
int questionNumber = random.Next(1, mineKategorier.GetLength(1));
string category = mineKategorier[categoryNumber, 0];
string question = mineKategorier[categoryNumber, questionNumber];
```

I used `1` in the second line because you are using the first entry of every row for the name of the category.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is generate a random number that is between 0 and the length of the array.

```
var random = new Random();
var randomYIndex = random.Next(0, mineKategorier.GetLength(0));
var randomXIndex = random.Next(0, mineKategorier.GetLength(1));
var randomQuestion = mineKategorier[randomYIndex, randomXIndex];
```

This will create a new `Random` and when you call `Random.Next` you are saying I want a value between 0 and the length of your array (but not the value of the length of your array). So if your array was of length 10, the random would produce a value between 0 and 9 with which you can then index into the array of questions.

The call to `GetLength` will get the length of the array of each index of your array, so `GetLength(0)` will return 10 and `GetLength(1)` will return 6 in your instance.

Answer (score -2):

```
Random r1 = new Random();
Random r2 = new Random();

int column = r1.Next(0, 10);//here 10 is for first length
int row = r2.Next(0,6)// here 6 for 2nd length. you can use variable here also.

//now  just pick from mineKategorier[,];
var value = mineKategorier[column,row];
```

Comment: Use the same instance of `Random`. Do *not* instantiate multiple instances. This is to avoid having the same clock-based seed value given to the different instances, due to quick-enough code execution.